# When is a countable language a non-recursive Language?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm studying Gödel's theorem this days. In my notes, as preliminarities I have the following definition:

Let $L$ a language. A *recursive arithmetization* of $L$ is a one-to-one mapping $\pi: L\longrightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that the following are recursive:

1. $\{\pi(c)\ :\ c\in L\text{ is a constant }\}$
2. $\{\pi(f)\ :\ f\in L\text{ is a function symbol}\}$
3. $\{\pi(R)\ :\ R\in L\text{ is a relation symbol}\}$
4. $\{\langle\pi(s), n\rangle \ :\ s\in L\text{ is an $n$-ary function symbol or relation symbol}\}$

We say that $L$ is *recursive* if there is a recursive arithmetization of $L$.

Obviously, any uncountable language is not recursive, my question is when is a countable language not recursive. In particular:

If I have a language $L$ with infinite symbols satisfying the conditions of the sets above (infinite constant symbols and infinite $n$-ary function an relation symbols for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$) I can order this symbols (say $\{c_m \ :\  m\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is the set of all constant symbols and $\{f_m^n\ :\ m\in\mathbb{N}\},\ \{r_m^n \ :\ m\in\mathbb{N}\}$ are the sets of all $n$-ary function and relation symbols).

Then I can consider the function $\pi: L\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ given by $\pi({c_m})=2^2\cdot 3^m$, $\pi(f_m^n)=2^2\cdot 3^n\cdot 5^m+1$ and $\pi(r_m^n)=2^2\cdot 3^n\cdot 5^m+2$ which I think it is a recursive arithmetization.

If this is the case and I'm no wrong, then I can take any numerable language, $\hat{L}$, and extend it to an infinite language like the one above and, once I have a recursive arithmetization to the extended language, I have a recursive arithmetization for $\hat{L}$ which is just the restriction of the other one.

So, if my guessing is correct, What is the nuance added by this definition? What is the difference between a countable language and a recursive one?

Comment: I think you are right and the point is that we *already assume* a recursive encoding of the symbols in the language, that will be inevitable in encoding the formulas.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is condition 4. Let $S$ be a non-recursive set of natural numbers. Consider a language $L$ which has a single $n$-ary relation symbol $R_n$ for all $n\in S$, and no other symbols. If you have such a mapping $\pi$, then the set of pairs in condition 4 is $\{(\pi(R_n),n):n\in S\}$. But this set is not recursive since its projection to the second coordinate is $S$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have been thinking in your idea and I think I see now the problem. I think that the mistake in my reasoning before was assuming that the restriction of $\pi$ from $L$ to $\hat{L}$ should give recursive sets since $\pi$ does, but this is incorrect, right?